# Android room database migration is running multiple times

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am using room database for creating local storage, I am trying to migrate database and I am getting issue while migrate function is called multiple times.

I am attaching my piece of code here.

```
class DbInstance {
companion object {
    private var db: AppDatabase? = null
    fun getDbInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        if (db == null)
            db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java, "mydb"
            )
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3)
                .build()
        return db!!
    }

    private val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

        }
    }
    private val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            println("------> called for MIGRATION_2_3")
            database.execSQL(
                "Alter table PaymentDB add column ui_name text"
            )
        }
    }
  }
}



@Database(entities = arrayOf(PaymentDB::class), version = 3)
@TypeConverters(DbTypeConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun paymentDao(): PaymentDao
}
```

where `println("------> called for MIGRATION_2_3")` printed multiple time(twice).

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer yet?

Comment: I finally resolved it by checking it manually.

Comment: May not be related to your issue, but you should get application context in room database. `Room.databaseBuilder( context.applicationContext, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution by using this approch.

```
  if (DbInstance.getDbInstance(context.get()!!).openHelper.readableDatabase.version != Constants.DATABASE_VERSION) {
                        DbInstance.getDbInstance(context = context.get()!!)
                            .openHelper.readableDatabase.needUpgrade(Constants.DATABASE_VERSION)
                        DbInstance.getDbInstance(context = context.get()!!)
                            .openHelper.writableDatabase.needUpgrade(Constants.DATABASE_VERSION)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I ran into this issue because I was using multiple instances of my database.** If possible, you should stick to a single instance to avoid this problem. In my case, I needed a separate instances for the widget and notifications because they run in a separate app context from the Main app and it's complicated and messy with separate databases being the easiest solution.

**Kotlin extension to run before each migration:**

```
private fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.hasAlreadyDoneMigration(migration: Migration): Boolean {
    return version >= migration.endVersion
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val MIGRATION_5_TO_6: Migration = object : Migration(5, 6) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        if (database.hasAlreadyDoneMigration(this)) {
            return
        }
        
        // your SQL migration code here
    }
}
```

Update: you don't need to wrap your migration code in a transaction. It's already done. [migration docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/migration/Migration#migrate(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase))

> This method is already called inside a transaction and that transaction might actually be a composite transaction of all necessary Migrations.

Comment: Migrations are already executed in transactionsn